# Search Results (Show more results)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search box where users can search for other users in a few types of ways, firstname, lastname, username or email within a drop down. This drop down shows the top 8 results and then I show a link at the bottom saying find more results with the bit of text they may have inputted into the search.

So for instance if I type in JOHN but only type 'JO' of his name this is the value $_GET['t'] should send through to the searchresults page. So I got as far as the link. But I just don't know what the query should be

Show more results link

```
<a href='include/searchresults.php?ref=".$_GET['t']."'>Show More Results for ".$_GET['t']."</a>
```

SEARCHRUSULTS.PHP

```
    if(isset($_GET['t'])){
$_GET['t'] = str_replace(" ", "", $_GET['t']);
$_GET['t'] = str_replace("%", "", $_GET['t']);

$_GET['t'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['t']);

if(strlen($_GET['t'])>1){

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%".$_GET['t']."%' OR first LIKE '%".$_GET['t']."%' OR last LIKE '%".$_GET['t']."%' OR email LIKE '%".$_GET['t']."%' ORDER BY first ASC";
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

    if($count<=0){
        echo "No results found";
    }else{
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
        while($user_data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){}
```

Comment: how do you get 8 result only, you should be getting all result as you have not set any limit in your query.

Comment: You're using `mysqli` but you're not using placeholders. This is a bad idea. Seeing things like `$_GET['t']` inside your query should freak you out. You should never do this even if you've used the escape function. You miss one of these and there will be serious consequences.

Comment: above code looks fine then how can u get more results

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood. I have a drop down with a limit of 8 results. To show more you click the link and it takes you to the searchresults page where there is no limit and shows ALL results with the inputted letters of $_GET['t']

Comment: @tadman I'm pretty new to MYSQLI, I've just converted my whole site.By placeholders do you mean variables in the query?

Comment: I mean you should be using `?` instead of actual data, then using `bind_param` to assign the data to the placeholders. It's the only safe way to do it. [Several examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php) show how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using MATCH insted of LIKE is much faster.

```
$keyword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['t']);
$rowsperpage=8;
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (first, last, email) AGAINST ('+$keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)   ORDER by first LIMIT $rowsperpage"; 
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

and set `$rowsperpage` as you like.

For more result page do something like this

```
$rowsperpage=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rpp']);
<a href='include/searchresults.php?t=$keyword&rpp=$rowsperpage'>Show More Results for "$keyword"</a>
```

Comment: I just get a blank page. This looks close to what I need tho. Is it something to do with my link?

Comment: The link won't find those variables as the link is on the page with the drop down. And sends the $_GET['t'] variable through to searchresults.php

Comment: I've got it working. Just change first to 't' in the link. Thank you